# Como creo un grafico de dispersion con PHP?

Tags: php, variables, date

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla o gráfico de dispersión que muestre la cantidad de logueos exitosos y fallidos de un formulario PHP pero después mucho buscar no encontre ni un tutorial o algo para poder  guiarme.
Este es un ejemplo de lo busco 
https://imgur.com/a/UmeM3
De momento solo me interesa crear el gráfico y escribir las variables de X ( fecha o mes) y  Y (Números)

Comment: Normalmente se suelen hacer con JavaScript, mandando a este mismo los datos de php, hay muchas librerias para generar Charts, te dejo una : https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options/

Comment: Hola Beta. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte a mejorarlo. Si no has hecho nada aun, investiga, intenta y si tienes fallos pregunta siguiendo [sk].Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes cómo hacerlo con google charts. Lo único que tienes que hacer es pasarle los datos con PHP en la variable "data". El ejemplo es en concreto un gráfico de dispersión. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
          [ 4,      5.5],
          [ 11,     14],
          [ 4,      5],
          [ 3,      3.5],
          [ 6.5,    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Tienes un ejemplo de cómo quedaría el gráfico y el código justo en la parte de bajo en esta URL:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart

Comment: Hola. Tienes razón. De hecho, por ese motivo he editado la respuesta añadiendo la parte de código para que el compañero pueda verlo en caso de que alguna vez caiga el enlace. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por mejorarla. Recuerda para la proxima  vez esperar a que el autor mejore la publicacion antes de responder. Respondiendo preguntas de baja calidad , indirectamente se promueven este tipo de publicaciones. Un saludo

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez. Soy nuevo y he querido echar una mano. Mis disculpas. Un saludo.